# Is it possible to have a component update right after shouldComponentUpdate, but before the next component's ShouldComponentUpdate is called?

Tags: reactjs

So far I am loving React, but there is one part of my application (and unfortunately a crucial part) that I have hit a bit of a hiccup with.

When an item mounts or flushes updates to the dom, I need to do specific checks around the finalized HTML before I continue (for example, if the component's dom nodes are overflowing the container I need to move it to the next container).

The problem with this is `shouldComponentUpdate` is called for all of them before any of them have `componentDidUpdate`.  This means I have to wait until *all* components flush to the dom, before I iterate through them in order to calculate from top to bottom if they overflow their outer container, and if so I need to change some things up causing all components after that one to be forced to update.

For example if my parent has 20 components and the 3rd component overflows, I have to wait until all 20 components are flushed to the dom before I move the latter 17 components to the next container, just to repeat until all components fit inside their containers.

What I would love to happen is that the first component flushes, I check if it overflows, then the 2nd component flushes, then I check if it overflows, etc...  That will drastically decrease how much is flushing to the dom.

Is this at all possible with Reaact?

If you are curious on the why behind this question, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467573/is-it-possible-to-manipulate-components-based-on-the-actual-laid-out-html-in-rea)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to directly cause React to sequentially call `shouldComponentUpdate` between component DOM flushes. In fact, that could dramatically and negatively affect the performance gains often realized by new React code by flushing all DOM changes between each call.

Instead, I believe you'll need to move to a model where a container component iteratively renders the children components either on- or off-screen and then lays out the children appropriately. The parent component would need to use the callback `componentDidUpdate` to measure children after they have rendered. Then, using `setState` for example, trigger the addition of a new child until the loop was complete. Eventually, all children will be rendered. This technique should operate relatively quickly and isolates the DOM and measuring of components as much as possible (rather than impacting the entire page for example). If you could render the children to an off-screen component/DOM element for measurements, it may be slightly faster. In fact, if you could render all the children off-screen in a single pass for measurements, that might be ideal.